# geotools 10 RC1 + hsqldb 2.3

Tags: java, swing, hsqldb, geotools

I'm currently working on a Swing project that uses hsqldb 2.3 as an optional database...
This project has a map, and geotools also uses hsqldb, however it uses hsqldb 1.8.
I tried to put them both working together but I get this exception:

"**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcDataSource**"

I checked the source code, and I believe the reason it happens is because on 2.3 the "jdbc" word is in upper case:
"org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource"

I don't know what to do from here. If I add both jars I will get a class conflict error.
Any suggestion is welcome....

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are also some other dependencies on hsqldb 1.8. You can start by modifying GeoTools and changing references to the new class. The SQL statements in GeoTools scripts are generally compatible but some usage may need updating. You will find out if you get an error when the scripts are run.

https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/plugin/epsg-hsql/src/main/java/org/geotools/referencing/factory/epsg

Note there is some use of CREATE ALIAS in source code which may be redundant and can be removed.

See the resources directory in the same source tree for the SQL.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that would generate some complicated solution.
I decided to use H2 as the embedded database. Worked fine and I don't need to change anything within a framework.
Plus I got to know H2 which is a really powerfull tool as the simplicity it offers.